# How to use multiple [product_page id=”101″] shortcode in a post?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I want to post 3 of my products using [product_page id=”101″] shortcode on a single post and shortcode does work properly but the problem is with the description!
eg. if i use 3 product_page id shortcode on a post like

> [product_page id=”101″] [product_page id=”102″] [product_page
>   id=”103″]

But on a post it only shows description of a last product which is 103!
101 and 102 description goes blank (you need to click on description tab to see it instead of direct view)
I want to show all the product description as it is on a post!
How do i resolve it?
Solution is heartly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: before asking any question please read this one https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset post data using wp_reset_postdata(); after every product details to print. and reset all your variable and check again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mr.Ajay & can you tell me where to put that code into my post and what variable to reset?I'm a newbie!